# Seven-segment display using 595

Tags: c, arduino

I am having some trouble coding my seven-segment display using a shift register and push button. The aim is for the display to count up when the button is pressed. 0-9 then; A, B, C, D, E, and F. I did manage to get this working at first but the task was changed so the "shiftOut" command was not allowed to be used.

With my adjusted code my seven-segment display doesn't seem to be working at all now. I have tried to do a lot of my own troubleshooting (i.e. looking into debouncing, arrays, and bit-banging). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. PS: this is my first question so sorry if the format is wrong.

```
/* Pins to connect to common-cathode LED display via a 74HC595:
 DP-7, A-6, B-5, C-4, D-3, E-2, F-1, G-15
 */

const byte ledCharSet[128] = {
  // 00-0F: Hex digits
  B10000001, B11001111, B10010010, B10000110,   // 0123
  B11001100, B10100100, B10100000, B10001111,   // 4567
  B10000000, B10000100,                         // 89
  B10001000, B11100000, B10110001, B11000010,   // AbCd
  B10110000, B10111000,                         // EF
};

//// Pin connected to latch pin (ST_CP) of 74HC595
const int latchPin = 8;
//// Pin connected to clock pin (SH_CP) of 74HC595
const int clockPin = 12;
//// Pin connected to Data in (DS) of 74HC595
const int dataPin  = 11;
//// Pin connected to display's common annode
const int faderPin = 10;
int _B = 7;
bool b;
int count=0;
int value;
long time = 0;
long debounce = 500;

void setup() {
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin,  OUTPUT);
  pinMode(_B, INPUT_PULLUP);
  b = true;
  toggleLatch();
  toggleCLK();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void toggleLatch() {
    digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH); digitalWrite(latchPin, OUTPUT);
}

void toggleCLK() {
  digitalWrite(clockPin, HIGH); digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned char count; // debounce counter
  if (b != digitalRead(_B)) {
    for(count = 0; count<20 && b != digitalRead(_B); count++);
    //register the change if we have confirmed it 20 consecutive times
    b=((count>=20 && b!=digitalRead(_B))?!b:b);
    if(!b) {
      count--;
    } // button is pushed
  }
  toggleLatch();

  void shiftBit(bool dataPin) { digitalWrite(ledCharSet,dataPin); toggleCLK(); }

  void shiftByteMSF(unsigned char b) {
    unsigned char b = ledCharSet[count];
    unsigned char m; // use m to select the bits in b one at a time
    m = 1;
    for (m = B10000000; m>0; m <<= 1) {
      if (b & m) {
        digitalWrite(dataPin, HIGH);
      } else {
        digitalWrite(dataPin, LOW);
      }
    }
    toggleLatch();
  }
  if (count==16) {
    count=0; //reset
  }
}
```

This is the first code I used, which worked fine.

```
/* Pins to connect to common-cathode LED display via a 74HC595:
 DP-7, A-6, B-5, C-4, D-3, E-2, F-1, G-15 (shiftOut using MSBFIRST)
 */

const byte ledCharSet[128] = {
  // 00-0F: Hex digits
  B10000001, B11001111, B10010010, B10000110,   // 0123
  B11001100, B10100100, B10100000, B10001111,   // 4567
  B10000000, B10000100,                         // 89
  B10001000, B11100000, B10110001, B11000010,   // AbCd
  B10110000, B10111000,                         // EF
};

//// Pin connected to latch pin (ST_CP) of 74HC595
const int latchPin = 8;
//// Pin connected to clock pin (SH_CP) of 74HC595
const int clockPin = 12;
//// Pin connected to Data in (DS) of 74HC595
const int dataPin  = 11;
//// Pin connected to display's common annode
const int faderPin = 10;
int _B = 7;
int reading;
int previous = LOW;
int counter=0;
long time = 0;
long debounce = 500;

void setup() {
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin,  OUTPUT);
  pinMode(_B, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  reading = digitalRead(_B);
  Serial.print(counter);
  if (reading == HIGH && previous == LOW && millis() - time > debounce) {
    counter++;
    time = millis();    
  }
  previous = reading;
  byte bitsToSend = ledCharSet[counter];
  bitsToSend = bitsToSend ^ B11111111;
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, bitsToSend);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11, 255);
  digitalWrite(11, 0);
  if (counter==16) {
    counter=0; //reset count
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure about `for (m = B10000000; m>0; m <<= 1) {`?  Maybe `m >>= 1`

Comment: @chux thanks, I have just noticed that was the wrong way around. i have changed it so now the display lights up, which is a plus.